# weight issue when mirroring bones

Tags: rigging

I'm currently learning how to rig in Blender. I've been weight painting on this model for a while, then the client asked for me to alter the hands. So I altered the mesh and made some major adjustments to the arms, I deleted the bones from the old right arm, selected the left and mirrored the bones for the right side.

The issue began when I went to alter the weights, the left arm still had weights assigned to the right arm bones. I manually painted all the weights to '0', everything was dark blue, but the left arm mesh would still warp every time I moved a bone from the right arm.

example here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CMQIOIcApSWAAV45Zo4IGLnXv_FAuP-M/view?usp=sharing

I figured, maybe if I removed the weight altogether from the right shoulder bone using the Object Data Properties tab and assign the bone to '0', it would also remove any influence on the left. Unfortunately, it hasn't worked.

I'm a bit stumped, if there's anyone who knows how to resolve this, it'd be a great help thank you.

Comment: Hello, please share your file (remove some non-important parts if you want): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: hello, this is the file https://pasteall.org/blend/e76893c0a82444959a886333f2e026d8

Comment: You could select the whole left arm in Edit mode and on the right of the Vertex Groups list > down arrow > Remove from All Groups. Then select the armature, shift select the object, switch it to Weight Paint mode, select the bone you want and Weights > Assign Automatic from Bones. Or reparent With Automatic Weight, in that case you first need to remove some overlapping vertices (select all and Merge by Distance).